# Same-type notifications on a followed post should appear once in the inbox

Tags: feature-request, notifications, follow-posts

When [following a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network), you get notified of different related actions (comments, edits, etc.) on that post as if you were tagged in a comment.

When tagged in multiple comments from the same post, it will only appear ***as one notification*** (with the number indicating how much comments there are):

[image]

***But***, when following a post, ***each notification will appear separately***, even if it's from the same type (comment for example):

[image]

To reduce inbox cluttering, I believe it makes sense to follow the same functionality as regular comments and merge the three notifications seen above into one. I would have no problem having different types of notifications appear separately (as seen above, *comment* and *closed*), but it seems redundant to have 3 notifications for comments. I mean, I will probably see all of them when I click on the first...

Comment: Despite the inbox cluttering, I actually like seeing (and also having links to) how many comments appear on a followed post, so having a single notification per comment makes sense to me, personally.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a good idea. And if you do that with comments, what about answers? Do you want to merge those as well?

Comment: @41686d6564 why not? If I open my inbox and see one notification which actually holds, let's say, 3 new answers - I will see them when I click that notification... I don't see a reason to have three separate notifications...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Suppose you follow a post that already had 10 or more answers (not uncommon for Meta.SO and Meta.SE posts, especially [featured] ones). Now, if the question received 3 more answers and you get only one notification, you'd have to scroll up and down looking for the new answers (possibly navigate through pages as well) as opposed to just clicking the notification and it redirects you to the relevant answer.

Comment: @41686d6564 Well...... Now I don't know what to do because I actually agree with you... I guess I was looking at this from a prespective of usually following new posted, new-users' questions which usually don't have lots of activity. But you raise an interesting case and I guess I would also prefer separate links on a busy page... Should I delee this question? lol

Comment: I wouldn't delete it. It's always good to get different perspectives, so let's see what the community has to offer. I actually do agree that cluttering the inbox with notifications is a problem; I just don't think what you proposed is an ideal solution. Perhaps someone else will come up with a creative one and post it as an answer. That's one reason to keep the question alive. It's your decision in the end though.

Answer (score -9):

Completely agree with this. I feel like inbox cramming isn't great, especially for those who wants to look back at certain questions they answered or followed.

Also, you can see the other comments once you click on the notification.

So yes, totally agreeing with this solution.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your support. I believe the reason for these down-votes is because your answer doesn't really answer the question... Showing support or disagreement is done through voting on meta. Answers are more for posting fixes or alternative solutions

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hello. Thank you too. Though these downvotes may seem nothing to me, I appreciate the support you gave me.